# Android bottom sheet behavior not working properly.Views not show on first run

Tags: android

Good day i have an app with bottom sheet behavior support.No matter what i have tried,the bottom sheet will not show the elements inside it on first initial show of it.The second time the same code triggers,the bottom sheet shows the element.This is happening with both:dynamically added views and listview as well.Here is my xml constructed for bottom sheet.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="brijhelpline.testproject.MapsActivity" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/settings"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/user" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/settings_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Fuel Buddy"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/searc_layout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/marker"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/marker_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_icon" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputStation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/marker"
            android:hint="Поиск Заправки"
            android:maxLines="1" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutToAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
    <!--<ListView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/listView"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>-->
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

As you can see the listview is commited,so i tried with every possible ways,even replacing the NESTEDSCROLLVIEW with RELATIVELAYOUT or whatsoever.And here is the code which actually adds view to the linearLayout.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < loopContent; i++) {
                    String address = addresses.get(i).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                    String city = addresses.get(i).getLocality();
                    String state = addresses.get(i).getAdminArea();
                    String country = addresses.get(i).getCountryName();
                    String postalCode = addresses.get(i).getPostalCode();
                    String knownName = addresses.get(i).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
                    if (knownName.equals("null") || knownName.toString().isEmpty()) {
                        knownName = "Нету информации";
                    }
                    if (address != null) {
                        if (address.toString().isEmpty() || address.equals("null")) {
                            address = "Нету информации";
                        }
                    } else {
                        address = "Нету информации";
                    }
//                    holder = new Holder(knownName, address);
//                    holderArrayList.add(holder);
//                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
                    View inflatedLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null, false);
                    TextView header = (TextView) inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.header);
                    TextView street = (TextView) inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.second);
                    header.setText(knownName);
                    street.setText(address);
                    layoutToAdd.addView(inflatedLayout);
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

I am fully clueless on what is the isssue and what to do with it...It is really annoying me already so if anyone can help me out,i would fully appreciate that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So far I have found that it is a bug from Google, meanwhile there is a workaround I found. Whenever you want to do the actual show set up, no matter if it is collapsing or expanding, just post a new runnable and do the set up like:

```
  bottomSheet.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(200);
                        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: thank you that helped me a lot, I wonder if Google will solve the bug

Comment: After spending 2 hours, this is what fixed the problem. Thank you

Comment: unfortunately, not work if i click on button of item recycler view with long length

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the problem in collapsing the bottom sheet. I solved by setting the peak height.

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
```

If you want BottomSheet to be collapsed and hid, you can add the code like this after you initialized your BottomSheetBehavior:

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me, Like on some Pre-Lollipop devices bottom sheet does not work

```
  ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(coordinator, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(coordinator);
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yyyessssss that works, surprisingly. Should definitely be the accepted answer. Do we know why and whether it's a bug or not?
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Instead of setting

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
```

Do this

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN ? BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED : BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```